# Consigli per una mail formale

Tags: formal

Vorrei scrivere un'email formale all'ufficio immigrazione.

Per iniziare un’e-mail ci si rivolge al destinatario con un saluto di circostanza, composto da un aggettivo di circostanza (Egregio, Esimio, Gentile, Caro, Carissimo…), però in questo caso non conosco il nome del destinatario.

Ho pensato di scrivere una cosa del genere:

```
Gentile Responsabile dell'Ufficio Immigrazione della Questura di xx,
```

Ma non mi sembra giusta come frase, sono un po' confuso su come iniziare la mail.

Comment: Mi sono permesso qualche minuscolo ritocco linguistico.

Comment: Io preferisco di gran lunga "egregio" a "gentile".

Comment: @Bruno9779: L'uso formale tradizionale voleva “egregio” se ci si rivolgeva a un uomo e “gentile” se a una donna, ma ora è largamente ignorato. Qui non sappiamo il sesso del destinatario, e “gentile responsabile” ha il pregio di evitare il problema.

Comment: @DaG Sono completamente insensibile alle sottilezze del gender-neutral, comunque è buono a sapersi. D'altro canto, gentile mi è sempre suonato un po ruffiano nelle lettere formali.

Comment: Si potrebbe usare "Spett.le Responsabile...." oppure "Alla cortese attenzione del Responsabile..."

Comment: È tuo pieno diritto essere insensibile, @Bruno9779, ma il problema, per l'OP, è se lo sia o no il/la responsabile dell'ufficio immigrazione.

Comment: @Bruno9779, per carità, potresti scrivere gli accenti in modo corretto? Li sto correggendo in tutti i tuoi commenti. Dici che dovrei evitare alcune delle mie domande perché provengono da siti web di pessima qualità... Non vorrei che anche questo sito dovesse essere considerato come di scarsa qualità per avere un'ortografia poco accurata.

Comment: @Charo No. La tastiera spagnola che uso ha il tasto AltGr rotto, solo mi funzionano gli accenti verso destra.

Comment: @Bruno9779 Ho rimosso parte del commento. Ti prego di moderare il linguaggio.

Comment: Non ti preoccupare, @Bruno9779: sapendo che hai questo problema, cercherò di correggere i tuoi accenti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come hai scritto va benissimo, comunque, se vuoi scrivere una lettera in stile burocratico, adotta questo tenore:

```
                            Al Responsabile dell'Ufficio Immigrazione 
                                                 della Questura di xx
                                                            Indirizzo


Il sottoscritto, Hatem Alimam, nato a ____, il ____, residente _______

                             CHIEDE

....
```